# characteristics

Tags: matlab, math, pde

I want to be able to simulate a hyperbolic equation on characteristic curves (lines). I will start with a basic one. u_{t}+2u_{x}=u^{2} with initial data u(x,0)=cos(x). The solution is u(x,t)=cos(x-2t)/(1-t*cos(x-2t)) where the characteristic curve is x=2*t+x_{0}. So the solution is defined on characteristics (method of characteristics).

```
x=zeros(10,5);
u=zeros(10,5);
x0=linspace(0,10,10);
t=linspace(0,5,5);
for i=1:length(x0)
    for j=1:length(t)
        x(i,j)=2*t(j)+x0(i);
        if t(j)*cos(x(i,j)-2*t(j))==1
            u(i,j)=0;
        else
            u(i,j)=cos(x(i,j)-2*t(j))/(1-t(j)*cos(x(i,j)-2*t(j)));
        end
    end
end
```

I'll be thankful if anyone can see my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I am not certain exactly if this solves your problem but you are accessing elements of your `t` matrix using the `i` and `j` indices. For example:

```
  (1-t(i)*cos(x(i)-2*t(j))
```

Since `i` can take values beyond the range of your `t` array, it is possible that you are mixing up your indices. At the very least you could be getting errors from accessing an element of `t` that is beyond its range. It is hard to say as you don't specify an error. I am just pointing out a potential problem.

It seems to me that you should use `i` to access elements of `x0` and `j` to access elements of `t` since these are within the limits you specify in your loops. Maybe

```
for i=1:length(x0)
    for j=1:length(t)
        x(i,j)=2*t(j)+x0(i);
        if t(j)*cos(x(i)-2*t(j))==1
            u(i,j)=0;
        else
            u(i,j)=cos(x(i)-2*t(j))/(1-t(j)*cos(x(i)-2*t(j)));
        end
    end
end
```

is what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. When I plot u(mesh u), I get a funny figur, which I does not want to see. Do you think that I also have a grid problem: from characteristic lines to rectangular grid?

Comment: @user1018331 I cannot say for sure. If you have a different problem with the plotting it is probably better to open a new question and provide specific details of the new problem. Otherwise it can become confusing. Maybe including some image of your plot in the new question if it helps